# Unit test framework for SDK2 apps

Tags: rally

Does anybody have a recommendation for unit testing home grown rally apps?

I've started to look at [Jasmine](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/guide/testing) as recommended in the Sencha docs and it looks promising, but I'm a little unsure about how to tie in all the Rally infrastructure, and I'm not a Javascript expert.

If anybody has used Jasmine for this, do you have some examples of how to set up a basic configuration for using Jasmine to test a SDK2 Rally app?

Answer (score 1):

One of the next things I wanted to create in my [app building](https://github.com/ferentchak/rally-app-builder) framework was a tie to some testing framework. I was leaning towards [Zombie](https://github.com/assaf/zombie), you may want to check that one out.